# Animate UILabel text size increase and decrease

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to apply animation on UILabel text. I write the code to increase font size in animation block but animation is not applied.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil/*contextPoint*/];
    monthsOnBoard.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"digital-7" size:150];
    daysOnBoard.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"digital-7" size:150];
    hoursOnBoard.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"digital-7" size:100];
    minutesOnBoard.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"digital-7" size:100];
    secondsOnBoard.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"digital-7" size:100];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:4];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The font of a UIView is not an animatable property. You should use transforms instead.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil/*contextPoint*/];
monthsOnBoard.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0); //increase the size by 2
 //etc etc same procedure for the other labels.
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:4];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

similarly, you can play with the values in `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(x, y);` - x is the horizontal scale constant and y is the vertical one. Enjoy!!

Comment: one more thing is that monthsOnBoard.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0); should be after [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

Comment: Well what I usually see is to set every animation attribute, (like setAnimationCurve) right after beginAnimations method, then list the changes to be animated and use [UIView commitAnimations]. However, I don't think it makes any difference, the order methods before commit animations shouldn't matter. To be honest, I never use this way of animation anymore. You should look in to block animations (they start like [UIView animateWithDuration:....], try them out too!!

Answer (score 1):

it may be help you

```
 monthsOnBoard.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(monthsOnBoard.transform, 1, 1); 
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil/*contextPoint*/];
    monthsOnBoard.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(monthsOnBoard.transform, 4, 4); 
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:4];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```